# Jenkins Pipeline, downstream job and Agent label

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline that executes Job A and Job B. I have 10 agents/nodes on which Job A is executed.
If I specify Agent1, when I Build Pipeline, then Job A should execute on Agent1.

Issue:
Pipeline is running on Agent1 and JobA is getting picked up on any random available agent.

Script:

`pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('JOB A') {
            agent { label "${machine}" }
            steps {
                build job: 'JOB A', parameters: [a,b,c,d,e,f]
            }
            }
        stage('JOB B') {
            agent { label 'xyz' }
            steps {
                build job: 'JOB B', parameters: [a,b,c,d,e,f,]
            }
            }
        }
    }`

I'm using different label for every agent.

Can someone help me understand how and where the Pipeline and downstream jobs are running?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807254/7983309

Comment: You specified agent label for stage, not for the JOB A. I think JOB A will find an available agent from the `Restrict where this project can be run` you configured in  JOB A's configuration.  Thinking about JOB A will be executed on which agent when you manually build JOB A.  Trigger JOB A in pipeline stage just make the trigger automatically.  But the JOB A behavior should same as trigger manually.

Answer (score 3):

As rightly pointed by @yong, I 'specified agent label for stage, not for the JOB A'.

So I declared a label parameter in JOB A and passed it downstream via the Pipeline. It's now correctly executing on the specified Agent.

```
pipeline {
agent { label 'master' }
stages {
    stage('JOB A') {
        steps {
            build job: 'JOB A', parameters: [a, [$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'Agent', label: "${Agent}" ], b, c, d]
        }
        }
    stage('JOB B') {
        steps {
            build job: 'JOB B', parameters: [x,y,z]
        }
        }
    }
}
```